# Will a surname change after marriage invalidate the UK resident permit?

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

I'm an EU citizen and my wife has a resident permit as an EU-national spouse.
She now wants to change her surname to take mine and will have to get a new passport.

Will she lose her current resident permit since it's affixed to her old passport?

Answer (score 3):

Normally she'll get the cancelled passport back and be able to continue using the residence permit. Regardless, she retains her right of residence even without the permit. To minimize confusion and hassle, however, it might be worthwhile to pay the £65 for a new permit in her new name.

Comment: Yes, I know she doesn't actually need it but in few occasion we've been asked for a proof of right to stay. The resident permit does the job :) I suppose we need to check with her embassy if they return the old passport then...